# Can I prevent an alert() with a Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, alert, google-chrome-extension

Can I create a Google chrome extension to prevent the page from doing an `alert()` ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As @MrGlass said, currently, Chrome Extensions run in a separate environment, limiting access to the actual `window` object and providing a duplicate that is only valid for the extension.

To solve this, we can inject a script element directly into the document. This way, you access the document's environment and the real `window` object.

First, lets create the function (I added the "confirm" as well, because some confirms were annoying me so much):

```
var disablerFunction = function () {

    window.alert = function alert(msg) { console.log('Hidden Alert ' + msg); };
    window.confirm = function confirm(msg) { 
        console.log("Hidden Confirm " + msg); 
        return true; /*simulates user clicking yes*/ 
    };

};
```

Now, what we're going to do is to transform that function in a text script and enclose it in parentheses (to avoid possible conflicts with actual vars in the page environment):

```
var disablerCode = "(" + disablerFunction.toString() + ")();";
```

And finally, we inject a script element, and immediately remove it:

```
var disablerScriptElement = document.createElement('script');
disablerScriptElement.textContent = disablerCode;

document.documentElement.appendChild(disablerScriptElement);
disablerScriptElement.parentNode.removeChild(disablerScriptElement);
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: I tested your code with https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_alert , but it didn't work, can you help ?  https://github.com/redstoneleo/AlertRedirect

Comment: So... how does a noob like me actually use this code?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore either Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-023TBTjXBaEyavkxWzaAMQD3UROHGAcGufvEKId/DGc='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Answer (score 16):

Yes you can, alert() is just a JavaScript method, you can override its functionality by doing.

```
window.alert = function alert(msg) {
  console.log('Hidden Alert ' + msg);
};
```

Just remember to run that content script at document_start within the manifest via run_at manifest content script modifier.

I believe there is an extension that just does that. The developer names it Nice Alert.
https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ehnbelnegmgdnjaghgomaakjcmpcakhk

Comment: This method no longer works = javascript in a content script is sandboxed from the main page. This changes the alert function in the content script, but not the main page.

Comment: That's true @MrGlass. See my answer to know how to workaround that.

Answer (score -5):

Thank you. That helped. However, I realized I needed to do this to get it to work

```
location.href="javascript: window.alert = function(x) {console.log(x)};"
```

if I wanted to remove alerts and confirms, I can do

```
location.href="javascript: window.alert = function(x) {console.log(x)}; window.confirm = function(){return true;};";
```

Comment: how do you get anything into this "javascript:" context? When I try this, I can't call any of my functions.

Comment: Not sure, sorry. This may be an outdated answer now. I wonder why it got so many down votes. I think might have been running into the issue that @MrGlass commented as the answer to the previous question.