# Javascript alert: block if message contains certain word?

Tags: javascript, alert

I have a webapp that makes calls to a database. Every once in a while, we get a javascript alert dialog that says that the transaction was deadlocked. Honestly, we don't care if that happens because it's not an interactive app...it just displays data based on a timer and if it misses it this time, it's okay to display it next time around.

I know you can over write the alert method like so:

```
window.alert = function alert(msg) {
  console.log('Hidden Alert ' + msg);
};
```

(found at [Can I prevent an alert() with a Google Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963677/can-i-prevent-an-alert-with-a-google-chrome-extension))

The question I have is: *Is there a way to see if the message for the alert `.contains`a specific word or phrase, ignore the alert call if it does but display the alert otherwise?* Installing an extension to deal with this really isn't an option.

Clarification:

I know how to catch it if it does or doesn't but what code would I write to go ahead and display the alert like normal if I'm over writing the alert code?

Comment: can't you use a regex object on the 'msg'?

Comment: Right, sure. Then what? I can say (psuedo): If !msg.Contains("deadlocked"){someCode;}. I got that fine but what goes into "someCode"? What do I say to actually display the alert? Catching it and ignoring it isn't the problem

Comment: indexOf or regular expression FTW!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.oldAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function alert(msg) {
  if (not msg contains ...)
    window.oldAlert(msg);
};
```

Comment: This has merit. Hoping there's a more elegant way?

Comment: @MetalPhoenix - I can only suggest adjusting your definition of "elegant".

Answer (score 2):

```
window.default = window.alert;
window.alert = function alert(msg) {
  var word = 'foo';
    if (msg.indexOf(word) != -1){
        console.log('contains');
        // do what you wanna do if contains
    }else{
       window.default(msg);
    }
};

alert('foo');
alert('bar');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pnkcpvLj/

Here is my approach.

Comment: I clarified my question to address what you've done here. I want to still show the alert if it doesn't contain that special string. I don't know what that code should be.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to capture the original alert() function so you can call it if need be:

```
var origalert = window.alert;
window.alert = function(msg) {
   if (msg.IndexOf('whatever') >= 0) {
      origalert(msg);
   } else {
      ... whatever ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Igor said the same thing (more or less). I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to do that?

Comment: no, there isn't. You're trying to replace core functionality. if you did `window.alert = function(msg) { if (...) { window.alert(...); }` you'd just end up with a recursive call to your own function and kill the system.

Comment: Ah... well, can't blame a programmer for trying, huh? Thanks