# How to disable chrome alert notification?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to turn alert notification off by my extension. The alert function is a javascript built-in function and i override it like below in content script but it still works.

content script:

```
window.alert = function(){}
```

It does not turn it off. The problem is realy simple but it does not work and i am going crazy :)

manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [ "assets/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js", "assets/js/common.js", "assets/js/handlers.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
```

handler.js:

```
window.alert = function (msg) {
    debugger;
    console.log(msg);
}
```

Comment: You could probably look at the source of an extension that already does this, like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/alert-control/ofjjanaennfbgpccfpbghnmblpdblbef?hl=en

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I prevent an alert() with a Google Chrome Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963677/can-i-prevent-an-alert-with-a-google-chrome-extension) (note the accepted answer's top comment - it appears this can no longer be done)

Comment: It does not work for me. I have already tried it.

Comment: Dmitriy Khudorozhkov's answer is correct. I just wanted to stress that the code needs to be injected into the page. Running it in the sandboxed environment of the content script is not enough. (There will be 2 levels of injection: extension injects content script, content script then injects code into the page.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't switch off notifications globally in Chrome (at least, not that way).

By doing

```
window.alert = function(){}
```

you simply switch off notifications for your own extension (= your own `window` context). You can't do this globally for security reasons (think what malicious extension could do if this was possible).

Edit: you actually [can inject your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) into the content pages; but this is still not a "global" change that you seek. If you still want this, then:

`manifest.js` of your extension:

```
{
    "name": "MyExtension",
    ...
    "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*"],
    "content_scripts" : [{
        "js" : ["script.js"]
    }]
}
```

And your `script.js`:

```
window.alert = function(){}
```

Comment: @RockOnGom I've appended my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Dmitriy mention it must be injected to the page. It works great please vote for Dimitry i just added the answer for sharing my code.
contend script:

```
 function override_alert() {
        window.alert = function alert(msg) {
            console.log('Hidden Alert ' + msg);
        };
    }
 if (!document.xmlVersion) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.appendChild(document.createTextNode('(' + override_alert + ')();'));
        document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
 }
```

Comment: I used your code , but it didn't work, I tested with https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_alert , can you help here ?  https://github.com/redstoneleo/AlertRedirect

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time you might need to indicate document_end, and override_alert actually works:https://jsfiddle.net/n76Ltzdf/1/

Comment: Thanks ! but still didn't work in a Chrome extension, as you know , extension's content script runs in the sandboxed environment which is different from the example you provide !

Answer (score -2):

Could you try something like this?

`$(document).ready( function() {
            window.alert = function(){};
        });`

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question

Comment: Meaning was not "use jQuery". Meaning was "try call method after load page".