# How to block browser notifications/alerts on exit?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, notifications, alert, chromium

How can I block abusive browser notifications/alerts on exit that prevent the closing of tabs, such as this one:

[image]

Note: Notifications are **already** turned off in the browser's content settings on

*chrome://settings/content/notifications?search=notif*

and I do NOT want to manually add a site every time. I am using Chromium on Debian 9.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable chrome alert notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613727/how-to-disable-chrome-alert-notification)

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand the answer(s) there. I already disabled notifications in chrome://settings/content/notifications?search=notif

Comment: Keep searching.  This question has been asked dozens of times.  Basically, you can't turn it off.

Comment: There must be a reason this settings option exists. And there are reasons why people might want to use it. If notifications are disabled, they are not supposed to pop up

Comment: @jmargolisvt: Thanks, but I already read all related questions. And "you don't" is not an answer, sorry

Comment: Question has been edited. "How to disable chrome alert notification?" does NOT answer it. This is about notifications preventing the user from closing tabs (often abused by malicious popups)