# Mock navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension, pulseaudio

I want to be on a WebRTC call and hear the sound even though I don't have a microphone attached to the device.  The web app I'm using to join the VOIP call detects that I don't have a microphone and turns off my audio because it assumes that I want to call in.

I noticed that the web app is using `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices` to determine whether or not I have the proper devices installed to be on the call.  Is there any way I can mock that to return valid MediaDeviceInfo objects to trick the site into thinking that I have a valid microphone so I can stay on the call?

#### Edit pertaining to duplicate answer

I don't think I can just override navigator.enumerateDevices = function(){...}

The return value is a list of MediaDeviceInfo objects, which you can't create with the MediaDeviceInfo constructor.  But I'd love to know if anyone knows of a way to create some sort of response array that would satiate any consumer of that resolved promise on the page.

Comment: I suggest you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done. You will probably also want to read [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I prevent an alert() with a Google Chrome Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963677/can-i-prevent-an-alert-with-a-google-chrome-extension)

Comment: @Makyen, I have read those, and I don't really think they are relevent.  I already have a content script getting injected into the page and it has access to the page's JS.  The problem is that I don't know how to mock navigator.enumerateDevices with values that would keep the page from running into problems.  Seems like I can't create MediaDeviceInfo objects. You get `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal Constructor`.  Can I mock it with POJO's instead?  What attributes would those POJOs need to include?  Don't they need to have a stream associated with them at some point?

Comment: Based on brief testing, it is certainly possible to override `mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`. It's very unlikely it needs to be a `MediaDeviceInfo` Object. It's very unlikely the page JavaScript actually checks. A POJO, with appropriate properties, is nearly certain to be fine. The Object just needs to be close enough to a `MediaDeviceInfo` Object for the page JavaScript to think input is available. You have specifically stated that you don't have an audio input device. Thus, it can't actually get the audio input. So, it doesn't need to be perfect; just enough to fool the page JavaScript.

Comment: Without your code, and the actual code which you are attempting to get to accept the added Object, we can't say anything more than generalities. If you want to add a *complete* [mcve], including the code which needs to be spoofed, then the question would be sufficiently different/specific not to be a duplicate. Right now, all we can say is to override the default function to give the page JavaScript the Object it wants to see. That is basically what the proposed duplicate says, and shows how to do, in the very general case. A more specific question would be great, but we need the information.

Comment: Note that spoofing may require overriding more than just `mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`, but we can't know without the code which is supposed to be tricked. Depending on the code you may have to spoof `.getUserMedia()` too, maybe more. But, without the code for which this is being done, we can't know.

Comment: @thataustin Were you able to resolve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices` returns promise. Try the below snippet. You can add n number of devices.

```
var device1 = {
    deviceId: "default",
    kind: "audiooutput",
    label: "",
    groupId: "default"
}
device1.__proto__ = MediaDeviceInfo.prototype;
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices = function() { 
    return new Promise((res, rej)=>{res([device1])})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var device1 = {
    deviceId: "default",
    kind: "audiooutput",
    label: "",
    groupId: "default"
}
device1.__proto__ = MediaDeviceInfo.prototype; 
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices = function() { 
    return [device1]
}
```