# How to prevent alerts from showing up using chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When alerts show up multiple times, users can choose to prevent it from showing up again. So, are there any relevant chrome APIs which I can call in content script or so to prevent these alerts  automatically?

Comment: This is the same question as this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2963677/8390149
so here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2979114/8390149

Comment: You can use chrome.notifications API instead of alert.

Comment: Are you asking how to prevent the web page's in-page JavaScript from using `alert()`, or how to prevent your own code from showing alerts, or how to prevent your `alerts()` from having the option to not display them?