# Chromeless - click on browser popup

Tags: chromeless

I use chromeless to fill in and validate a form. The form generates a validation popup when I click on the submit button:

[image]

How do I click on this popup and validate the form?

Comment: Is that just a [`window.confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) dialog?

Comment: @zero298 I don't know how to check that but it looks like a default dialog, yes

Comment: Then I don't think there is a way yet.  Consider this issue on the project's GitHub: [chromeless#61](https://github.com/graphcool/chromeless/issues/61)

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at this as well.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963677/can-i-prevent-an-alert-with-a-google-chrome-extension

However, for validation pop-ups, the above linked GitHub page has the solution.

Answer (score 1):

using evaluate to overwrite window.confirm

```
chromeless.evaluate(() => window.confirm = () => true)
```